# create a number using 4 different digit

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have a problem to calculate how many numbers of n digit  that can be formed using four number 4,6,7,8. here condition is that each number should appear at least once in each number.

So i solved it like 
say i have n=5 so i have to create 5 digit number using these four number.

### then each place of 5 digit can be filled by 4 way(4,6,7,8)

so count of numbers = 4*4*4*4*4;

but it is not correct please help

Comment: What is the correct answer given?

Comment: Don't agree : for $n=5$, one and only digit is present twice in the code. There are $5$ ways to choose it, and $\binom52$ ways to choose the places where it goes. There are $3$ digits left, which can be placed in the $3$ remaining places in $3!$ different ways.
So the answer should be $5\times\binom52\times3!=300$

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS thanks man .how to generalize ur  solution ?say for exampel -no of  n digit number with three digit 4,5,6 .

Comment: @tatan for n=5 with three number 4,5,6 its 150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_{k,n}$ the set of codes of length $n$ written with the only number $k$ (for $k\in\{4,5,6\}$), $B_{k,l,n}$ the set of codes of length $n$ written with **at most** the numbers $k$ and $l$ ($k\ne l$), and $C_{4,5,6,n}$ the set of codes of length $n$ written with **at most** the numbers $4$, $5$ and $6$.

What you want to compute is the cardinal of 
$$C_{4,5,6,n}\setminus(B_{4,5,n}\cup B_{4,6,n}\cup B_{5,6,n})$$
But, as $B_{4,5,n}\cap B_{4,6,n}=A_{4,n}$, we have :
\begin{align}&{\rm card}(B_{4,5,n}\cup B_{4,6,n}\cup B_{5,6,n}) \\ =& {\rm card}(B_{4,5,n}) + {\rm card}(B_{4,6,n})+ {\rm card}(B_{5,6,n}) - {\rm card}(A_{4,n}) - {\rm card}(A_{5,n}) - {\rm card}(A_{6,n}) \\
=&2^n+2^n+2^n-1^n-1^n-1^n \\ =&3(2^n-1)
\end{align}
So the searched number is
$$3^n-3.2^n+3$$
For $n=4$, you find $3^4-3\times2^4+3=36$, which is also what you find by choosing the repeated letter : $3\times\binom42\times2!$. And for $n=5$, you find $150$, as mentionned above by @vks.

This calculation uses the principle of inclusion-exclusion, I think you can generalize it quite easily.

Comment: u grt man .thanks a lot